# Spring Framework integration test Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I wrote an integration test on a Spring Framework controller and the and test runs correct. Application runs correct too. I have some exceptions that i want to fix. I can not fix the nullpoiner exception which come from LoginController at line 34. I saw that loginDelegate but how ti fix this ?

**Controller class**

```
 @Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginDelegate loginDelegate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, LoginBean loginBean) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
        model.addObject("loginBean", loginBean);
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView executeLogin(ModelAndView model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @ModelAttribute("loginBean") LoginBean loginBean) {

        try {
            boolean isValidUser = loginDelegate.isValidUser(loginBean.getUsername(), loginBean.getPassword());
            if (isValidUser) {
                System.out.println("User Login Successful");
                request.setAttribute("loggedInUser", loginBean.getUsername());
                model = new ModelAndView("welcome");
            } else {
                model = new ModelAndView("login");
                request.setAttribute("message", "Invalid credentials!!");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return model;
    }
}
```

**Test Controller Class**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@WebAppConfiguration
@Configuration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml" })
public class LoginControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new LoginController()).setViewResolvers(viewResolver).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDisplayLogin() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/login")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("login")).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecuteLogin() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/login").param("username", "nikola").param("password", "pass")).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("login"));
    }

}
```

**spring dispacher servlet**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nikola" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginDelegate" class="com.nikola.integration.delegate.LoginDelegate">
        <property name="userService" ref="userService"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userService" class="com.nikola.integration.service.impl.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="userDao" class="com.nikola.integration.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="loginController" class="com.nikola.integration.controller.LoginController">
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/store" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nikola.integration.controller.LoginController.executeLogin(LoginController.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:144)
    at com.nikola.integration.controller.test.LoginControllerTest.testExecuteLogin(LoginControllerTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test, you are instantiating a new `LoginController` :

```
this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new LoginController()).setViewResolvers(viewResolver).build();
```

This new instance is not managed by spring and the @Autowired field is not injected.

You should inject in your test the LoginController defined in your configuration, and initialize the `mockMvc` with this instance :

```
@Autowired
private LoginController controller;

...

this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(c).setViewResolvers(viewResolver).build();
```

Comment: If i do it like this
@Autowired
private LoginController loginController;

this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(loginController).setViewResolvers(viewResolver).build();

I have nullpointer